# Подсчет количества комбинаций на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В алфавите языка n символов, а на сундуке всего n ячеек, в каждую из которых нужно ввести один символ. Символы в коде не могут повторяться! Сколько комбинаций нужно перебрать?

Я вот предполагаю, что пользователь вводит число n (n >= 1). Получается, что в первую ячейку можно записать n разных символов, во вторую n - 1 и так далее. Для подсчета количества комбинаций необходимо вычислить факториал числа n, который вычисляется по следующей формуле, которая на картинке. Но как это записать через цикл while?

Comment: Пробовали гуглить "python факториал"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35467382/10138734

Comment: Крик души. До абсурда доходят иногда авторы вопроса. Вставляешь в гугл/яндекс заголовок их вопроса и первая ссылка в выдаче дает исчерпывающий ответ. Зато как кристально ясно сформулировано, стоило ли потраченного времени. И больше получаса не ждал бы ответ, и людям бы шум не создавал, которые хотят отвечать на интересные вопросы.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще в `python` это делают так:

```
import math
n=int(input())
math.factorial(n)
```

Но через `while` можно так:

```
n=int(input()); f=1
while n!=1:
    f*=n
    n-=1
```

или так:

```
n=int(input); f=1; k=1
while k<n:
    f*=k
    k+=1
```

Или можно рекурсией:

```
def fact(n):
    if n==1 or n==0:
        return 1
    return n*fact(n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import math
>>> math.factorial(33)
8683317618811886495518194401280000000L
```

Comment: Но это же не "через цикл while"! :D

Comment: @Эникейщик Но так же проще :)

Comment: С этим трудно спорить :)

Comment: @Эникейщик зато заминусовать легко

Comment: Это да. Кому-то не понравилось :/

Comment: А что — нормальный ответ.

Comment: За что люблю питон - можно взять и просто так посчитать факториал от 33. Попробуй-ка такое провернуть где-нибудь в яве. Фигушки.

Comment: @Эникейщик Я люблю питон за тоже.Все делается просто, в одно касание.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica одним словом, язык для ленивых)

Comment: @finally CoC:"Сосредоточьтесь на содержимом, а не на личности. Не используйте слова, связанные с человеческими качествами (например, __«ленивый»__), даже если ими можно описать содержание сообщения." ;)

Answer (score 0):

Высчитывает факториал (только посложнее чем у n1tr0xs)

```
n=int(input())
C=1
for i in range(1,n+1):
    C=C*i
print(C)
```

Comment: Высчитывает факториал (только посложнее чем у n1tr0xs)